# Graph isn't an attribute in TensorFlow? Very basic question

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

Hi am am just starting to learn how to use TensorFlow and this is one of my first projects. I am simply trying to create a graph.

This is my code:

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    graph1 = tf.Graph()
```

I cannot seem to create a Graph. The compiler threw an AttributeError (not exactly sure what that is)...

```py
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

The compiler said the issue was with line two in creating the graph.

```py
    ----> 2 graph1 = tf.Graph()

    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Graph'
```

---

If it is of any use I am using a Jupyter Notebook in JetBrain's PyCharm. I believe I imported everything correctly but I am not sure if using PyCharm will mess anything up. Any help you be very appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2 options.**

reinstall and try again (dont ask)

option b) downgrade to versions 1.13.1 and lower (again dont ask)

---

- *ofcourse you can ask I am just lazy*

Comment: Ha installing 1.13.1 worked! Thanks so much @Noah Weber :)